# PowerPoint opens on second screen but I haven't one

Tags: windows-10, display

I'll open PowerPoint on my Window 10 computer but it looks like he opens PowerPoint to a second screen, but there is no second screen connected.

[image: Screen settings]

Sometimes it happen I enlarge my first screen but not today.

**Update:** If I click on the icon of PowerPoint on my task bar, the application moves to the direction of the arrows.

[image]
<sup>Click on image to view original size.</sup>

Comment: Could you clarify in your question what makes you think Powerpoint opens on a second screen? Is it because it shows up in the taskbar, but you don't see the application? Because that could also imply a bunch of other issues.

Comment: @Wouter; I've update my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can happen when we have previously connected an external screen.  If PowerPoint appears on the taskbar, right-click an empty space on the taskbar and select `Cascade windows` to see if it returns to the main screen.

If that doesn't work, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right-click the PowerPoint icon on the taskbar.  Choose `Move` and when the 4-way arrow appears, press one of the arrow keys and move your mouse.

[image: Move]

(Source:  [Bring Misplaced Off-Screen Windows Back to Your Desktop](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/bring-misplaced-off-screen-windows-back-to-your-desktop-keyboard-trick/))

Comment: Oooh, cool trick. Didn't know that. Testing this, you might have to do "restore" before "move" becomes available, if the window was maximized.

Answer (score 5):

This did not work for me.  Move never brought it to the screen.  However, a Shift + right-click >> Maximize brought it to the screen.  Then I clicked on the title bar and made is smaller and it stayed on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Press ALT+Space bar then press M

Use the arrow keys to move the window back onto the screen.  Once you get it to where it's controllable, press ENTER to quit move-mode.