# Window gets stuck at external screen

Tags: windows-10, external-display, window

I have the same problem as stated [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1153513/powerpoint-opens-on-second-screen-but-i-havent-one), but with games.

In short, what **doesn't** work:

- Shift+Right click, then Move option with arrow keys. The window never appears back at the first screen.
- Overlapping windows through taskbar. It overlaps the other windows, but not the one at the external screen.

What **does** work:

- Connecting external screen, then disconnect it. This resets the window back to the first screen, in the same position it was at the external screen.

But now I'm at a place where **I don't have external screen to use**. So, **how do I fix it**?

I've searched similar situations, but everyone was saying only about the same Move Windows option, which apparently doesn't work here (**Windows 10**).

Comment: If you hit `Win`+`P` to open the display switcher menu, what mode is selected? If it's set to `Extend`, does changing it help?

Comment: I've tried that several times before, while the game was running, didn't work. Now I tried it before I open the game and it worked...dafuq Windows :D. Thanks anyway, cause I tested it before the game, by fault :D.

Comment: Great, glad to help! Please mark the answer I just posted as accepted so others can see what worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the desktop, hit `Win`+`P` to open the `Project` menu:

[image]

Now select `PC screen only` or `Second screen only`, depending on your monitor setup. This tells Windows to only use one screen, even if you have two connected.